# Ionic2 + AngularFire2 Offline = memory leak

Tags: firebase, memory-leaks, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

**Update:** I've tested it again without the offline wrapper and it seems to work fine (I must have missed sth before) so the problem seems to be caused by the AngularFire2 Offline (https://github.com/adriancarriger/angularfire2-offline). Has anyone experienced similar issues?

I'm building an Android application in Ionic2 using Firebase as database and it looks like I have a memory leak which I wasn't able to fix so far. To load the firebase data, I'm using AngularFire2 and AngularFire2 Offline.

To test this problem, I've simplified the data structure and the app functionality. If it comes to data, I have a list of users and each user has a list of tasks (tasks are children of the user). In the application, I have 2 pages - the 1st one displays a list of users, the 2nd one displays selected user's tasks. Each task has a checkbox - once checked, the task's `isDone` flag is updated and the task is not displayed any more (I use the search pipe to only display tasks with `isDone == false`).

The problem is that every time when the task is updated, the memory usage increases significantly (by ~1MB). The screenshot below shows 3 snapshots:

1. After application is loaded and the list of users is displayed (33.7MB)
2. After list of almost 40 tasks is loaded (35.9MB)
3. After 15 tasks are updated (46.2MB)

[image: snapshots]

The memory usage never goes down - every update (even if I go to different user) increases it. After just a few minutes of testing it goes over 100MB and more. This leads to application crash on the Android device.

The code behind it:

- in the page html (loop beginning):

  ```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let task of tasks$ | async | search:'isDone':false">
  ```
- in the controller - getting tasks list (AfoListObservable):

  ```
  this.tasks$ = this.data.getTasks(this.userKey);
  ```
- in the controller - updating task:

  ```
  this.data.updateTask(this.userKey, task.$key, task);
  ```
- both methods in the data provider:

  ```
  getTasks(userKey: string): AfoListObservable<Task[]> {
      return this.db.list("/users/" + userKey + "/tasks");
  }

  updateItem(userKey: string, taskKey: string, task: Task): firebase.Promise<void> {
      return this.db.object("/users/" + userKey + "/tasks/" + taskKey).update(task);
  }
  ```

Comment: Are there any method calls from the html page?

Comment: There were, but I've removed all of them and the issue remains. It goes away when I use AngularFire2 without the offline wrapper.

Comment: without the offline wrapper means..? Please explain I'm facing same issue!

Comment: The offline wrapper is the npm library angularfire2-offline